Permission denied for GCR.IO Image
I have just spent the better part of 2 days trying the following docker command to get a public image from Google Cloud Artefact Registery. This is supposed to be a public image and I am the owner on the account, but I get the permission error below.
docker pull gcr.io/visionai-public-images/vaictl

Error:
Error response from daemon: Head "https://gcr.io/v2/visionai-public-images/vaictl/manifests/latest": denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/visionai-public-images/locations/us/repositories/gcr.io" (or it may not exist)

I am running gcloud-cli on my local machine, so I thought running this in cloud shell might be shed more light. The same problem persisted. I also tried searching the web for someone else who may have an issue with this specific image but found nothing.
When I attempt to access the gcr.io/visionai-public-images repository from a browser, I get a page that shows the following:
Missing permissions:
artifactregistry.repositories.get
artifactregistry.versions.list
I verified that I have these in the list of permissions in IAM.
I also reconfigured docker on my local machine by running gcloud auth configure-docker,  but it looks like I had already configured it.  The output is below:
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
    "us-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud"
  }
}

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?
I tried adding permissions, running gcloud configure-docker and searching the web for a solution.

gcr.io/visionai-public-images is not a publicly accessible artifact registry. If it was, you would be able to list the images using:
gcloud container images list --repository=gcr.io/visionai-public-images

But this errors with:
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) Bad status during token exchange: 403
b'{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Permission \\"artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts\\" 
denied on resource \\"projects/visionai-public-images/locations/us/repositories/gcr.io\\" 
(or it may not exist)"}]}\n'

(Try the same for an actual publicly available repository like gcr.io/google-containers and you will get a list of images).
If you are the owner of the GCP project that serves this artifact registry (you say you are 'the owner on the account') and want the images to be publicly available, assign the role Artifact Registry Reader to the allUsers group to fix this.
